Find the Isotropic Planes
Consider the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the bilinear form $\langle v, v\rangle = v_1 ^2+v_2^2 - v_3^2 -v_4^2$. Find all totally isotropic $2$-planes.
Note: A subspace $W \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is totally isotropic if   $\langle v, v\rangle = 0$ for all $v\in W$.
My attempt: Let $v \in W$ where $W$ is a isotropic $2$-plane. Then $v_1 ^2+v_2^2 = v_3^2 +v_4^2$. Now I cannot proceed further. Please help me.

Pick a linearly independent pair $v,w \in W$. Play around with different linear combinations of $v$ and $w$, each of which must also be an element of $W$. Try to observe patterns.

Write vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ as $v = (v_1, v_2)$, where $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then $\langle v, v \rangle = 0$ iff $||v_1|| = ||v_2||$ (with the euclidean norm). Now for a totally isotropic plane, choose a basis $(v, w)$ and without loss of generality assume $||v_1|| = ||v_2|| = ||w_1|| = ||w_2|| = 1$. But by choice we also have $||av_1 + bw_1|| = ||av_2 + bw_2||$ for each $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Squaring and expanding as dot products, you get $ab (v_1 \cdot w_1) = ab (v_2 \cdot w_2)$, and therefore $v_1 \cdot w_1 = v_2 \cdot w_2$. Reversing the above steps it follows that this is also sufficient.
Note that the dot product condition implies that $v_1 = \pm w_1$ iff $v_2 = \pm w_2$ and this is the only possible way either pair can be linearly dependent. Since $v$ and $w$ are linearly indepedent, we get that each $(v_i, w_i)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now a different choice of basis for the $\mathbb{R}^2$ spanned by $(v_1, w_1)$ exactly corresponds to a different choice of basis of the plane spanned by $(v, w)$, so again without loss of generality we can choose $v_1 = (1, 0)$ and $w_1 = (0, 1)$, which implies $v_1 \cdot w_1 = 0$. Therefore totally isotropic planes correspond uniquely to (ordered) pairs $v_2, w_2 \subset S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with $v_2 \cdot w_2 = 0$.
